# Get password from a user with UserManager

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity-2, usermanager

I'm making a website with MVC5 ASP.NET. 
I'm using Identity framework 2.0 implement class with properties such as passwordhash, username, email, emailconfirmed and so on. I'm using userManager.ChangePassword(user.Id, Oldpassword, Newpassword);, but i can't figure out how i should get a password from a user as plain text (string)

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult ChangePassword(AspNetUsersViewModel userView)
    {

        UserManager<IdentityUser> userManager = new UserManager<IdentityUser>(new UserStore<IdentityUser>());

        var result = userManager.ChangePassword(_User.Id, "123456789", userView.Password);

        return RedirectToAction("Index", "ConfigUser");

    }
```

As now I'm i have hardcoded users current password "123456789" to test if it works, and it does. 
I hope you guys can help.

Comment: What do you mean with "get a password from a user in plain text"?

Comment: @PaoloCosta For now a User only has a PasswordHash and a SecurityStamp property, not a directly Password property ("123456789"). And I'm using IdentityUser Implementation from Identity 2.0.

Comment: If it's a Hash you just can't retireve it. It's by design for security

Comment: That is understandable. But if a user want to change his/her password im using the function userManger.ChangePassword(id, old password, new password);, which need to know the users old password.

Comment: No, it just checks if the oldpassword is correct against the hash. The same operation it does to check the password when you login.

Comment: Do you have any code example which can help me? @PaoloCosta

Comment: The ASP.NET MVC5 starter templates contain a working version, all the code you need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Add password input to the View inside the form tag

   ```
     <input type="password" id= "userNewPassword" name="userNewPassword">
   ```
2. Pass the userNewPasswor as string to the controller after the userView and the pass it to the UserManager

   ```
     [HttpPost]
     public ActionResult ChangePassword(
               AspNetUsersViewModel userView,
               string userNewPassword){

                          UserManager<IdentityUser> userManager = new UserManager<IdentityUser>(new UserStore<IdentityUser>());
                          var result = userManager.ChangePassword(_User.Id, userNewPassword , userView.Password);
                          return RedirectToAction("Index", "ConfigUser");


                                    }
   ```

Note:  the Best way is to Modify the userView and add the userNewPassword to the model

Update:

in the visual studio 2013 the if you used the asp.net default template you will find the flowing class

```
public class ChangePasswordBindingModel
{
    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Current password")]
    public string OldPassword { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} characters long.", MinimumLength = 6)]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "New password")]
    public string NewPassword { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Confirm new password")]
    [Compare("NewPassword", ErrorMessage = "The new password and confirmation password do not match.")]
    public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I got your idea - thx. But how do I check if the "userNewPassword" is equal to the users current password?

Comment: the Change Password method will auto check the old password pass the prammeters 1.userId, 2.currentPassword, 3.newPassword you don't have to check it your self

Comment: if you want to hash the password use        UserManager.PasswordHasher.HashPassword(PlainTextOldPassword) it will give you the the hashed  password